# Amazon forecast takes long time to forecast

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-forecast

Like the title says the forecast generating takes a long time. I am updating the data (target and related data) and i already have pretrained a predictor. The target dataset is relatively small and it has granularity of 1 hour.

On each forecast generation it seems like the predictor retrains before it makes inference. I am trying to forecast 1 month ahead and the only solution I found is to reupload the data and make new forecasts with 24 hour forecast horizon( this is used for training the predictor).

The upload/import jobs/forecast generating and export take close to 1hour all together.

Is there anyway i can update the data and generate forecasts faster without letting the forecasting retrain on the newly added data?

Answer (score 0):

CreateForecast does not retrain the forecasting model. It just creates the forecast.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/howitworks-forecast.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)